# How to sync gitlab repository to remote server that uses ssh automatically

Tags: git, amazon-web-services, ubuntu, gitlab

So i have a remote ubuntu server on aws that uses ssh authentication access, and i usually uses filezilla to upload my changes from local one by one. I also have a gitlab repo that i usually use to just keep track of my changes.

When i push my changes from local to my gitlab server i want it to change in my remote server automatically. So kind of like syncing between remote server and my gitlab repo.

I have tried the Mirroring repositories available on gitlab by adding https://username:password@mygitserver.domain.com with authentication method password with my server passwod, but when i try to update my changes it shows this error on the mirrored repositories

```
13:get remote references: create git ls-remote: exit status 128, stderr: "fatal: unable to access 'https://myremoteserver.domain.com/': Failed to connect to myremoteserver.domain.com port 443: Connection refused\n".
```

then i tried the ssh://username:password@mygitserver.domain.com
but then it showed me this error

```
13:get remote references: create git ls-remote: exit status 128, stderr: "fatal: no path specified; see 'git help pull' for valid url syntax\n".
```

So can anyone tell me what did i miss ?

Comment: What command did you use? A simple `git clone <repo_url>` on the remote server should suffice for syncing.

Comment: I guess i should change the question, i meant when i push my changes from local to gitlab repo, it automatically changes on the remote server syncing on the gitlab repo so i dont have to clone it on the remote server it automatically synced.

Comment: You may want to look into Gitlab's CI/CD pipelines